# Session in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a project with login.aspx view.aspx etc etc....In the login page, after the user has been authorized, I have to open a Dynamic Data Entities application.
The problem is how to pass the value of the session containing the username while keeping the same sessionID?

Help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not share a asp.net session between two web applications I'm afraid.

Comment: and What can I do? the user log in the login.aspx, and I save in session["info"] the info of this user......the user click on a button "change config" and response.redirect("url of the dynamic data entities web application")......hier I lost the info of the user!

Comment: Depending on how sensitive the data you have, you could always do a post to a new page with the values you need as postvalues instead of a simple redirect. If you do a redirect you can send the values as querystring values. Not the most pretty solution, but it works in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the link below - very good summary of ASP.net single sign on options:

http://blogs.neudesic.com/blogs/michael_morozov/archive/2006/03/17/72.aspx

Comment: ok, It´s good, but in this case I pass only the value.....the session.sessionID isn't the same.
I want to pass the session (Session["value"], sessionID, LCID, etc etc ) and not only the value!